# number input with consolewrite wrongmessage

Tags: c#

i have been trying this for hours(im new at programming)!

question: put in two numbers. Try if the first number is two times as big as the secound number. Ans if the secound number is, make the console write:"the number is to big".

i have been trying back and forth with this code

```
        Console.WriteLine("insert number:");
        string strTal = Console.ReadLine();
        int input1 = Convert.ToInt32(strTal);




        Console.WriteLine("insert number :");
        int input2 = input1;
        Console.ReadLine();

        input2 = input2 * input1;

        if (input2 >= input1) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("the number is to big");
            Console.ReadLine();
       }
        else if(input2 <= input1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("the number is to small");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

I whould be really thankful if some one could get me a little push/help!!!

Comment: Why are you ignoring the result of your second call to `ReadLine()`? Why are you multiplying `input2` by `input1`?

Comment: You have to obtain `input2` in a same manner as `input1`. Then comparing them as you already do should work.

Comment: "Try if the first number is two times as big as the secound number. Ans if the secound number is" It is ( at least to me) unclear what you mean by this.

Comment: this code shows no effort or thinking. by the way it's horrible formatted and instructions are really unclear.

Comment: It's early and I haven't had my coffee yet, but I'm confused...   what is `input2 = input2 * input1;` doing?   How does that help us figure out if the first number is two times as big as the second number?

Answer (score 1):

Your `input1` will always be the same as `input2` because you do `int input2 = input1;`.

Try this for the second number:

```
Console.WriteLine("Insert number:");
string strTal2 = Console.ReadLine();
int input2 = Convert.ToInt32(strTal2);
```

And after that you can do this to check whether the second number is half as big as the first:

```
if (input1 == (input2 * 2))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was able to fix it by adding this and putting one extra "else" if the the number was lower then 2 times!

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you are setting input2 = input1, rather than setting it equal to a value input by the user, therefore the values for input1 and input2 will always be the same.

Comment: Thank you! i didnt think of that. Then i Changed the values!